React js onclick function is triggering where it should not
I added an on-click event listener button inside the table but it is not functioning properly
it keeps triggering while populating data.
console while populating data
after cleaning the console I clicked on buttons
but doesn't show anything when I click on these buttons
This is the function of below table
function FilterTable(props){
    const filterData=props.data;
    const clickEvent=(id)=>{ console.log('click event triggered',id)}
    //console.log(filterData)
    const ids=filterData.map((item,index) =>(item[Object.keys(item)[0]]))
    const firstdata=filterData[0]
    //console.log(ids)
    const cols=Object.keys(firstdata)
    cols.shift()
    
    return(
        <div className="foot-body ">
            <div className="table-col">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        {props.column.map((item,index) =>(
                            <th>{item}</th>
                        ))} 
                    </tr>                   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {filterData.map((item,index) =>(
                        <tr  id={ids[index]}>
                            <td>
                                <button onClick={clickEvent(ids[index])}>Select</button>
                            </td>
                            {cols.map((obj,inx)=>(
                                <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:item[obj]}}></td>
                                
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

and data passed in the parameter is
[
    {
        "custid": 1001,
        "firstname": "<mark>Cu</mark>stomer",
        "lastname": "example",
        "Contactno": "9999999999",
        "emailid": "cexamplea@example.com",
        "addressLine1": "1234 address Example",
        "addressLine2": null,
        "addressLine3": null
    },
    {
        "custid": 1002,
        "firstname": "<mark>Cu</mark>stomer",
        "lastname": "example",
        "Contactno": "9999999888",
        "emailid": "cexampleb@example.com",
        "addressLine1": "123 address Example",
        "addressLine2": null,
        "addressLine3": null
    },
    {
        "custid": 1003,
        "firstname": "<mark>Cu</mark>stomer",
        "lastname": "eg a",
        "Contactno": "9876543210",
        "emailid": "cexamplec@example.com",
        "addressLine1": "12374 address Example",
        "addressLine2": null,
        "addressLine3": null
    },
    {
        "custid": 1004,
        "firstname": "<mark>Cu</mark>stomer",
        "lastname": "eg",
        "Contactno": "9987564789",
        "emailid": "cexampled@example.com",
        "addressLine1": "1237 address Example",
        "addressLine2": null,
        "addressLine3": null
    }
]


am I declaring this trigger wrong? or there is any other way to call on click trigger

With onClick={clickEvent(ids[index])} you passing clickEvent function result and not listener. If you want to execute clickEvent onClick try to pass arrow function with your clickEvent like this: <button onClick={() => clickEvent(ids[index])}>Select</button>

I found the solution to my problem here:
React onClick function fires on render
Turns out I was calling the click event function instantly. Wrapping it in an anonymous function solves it:
<button onClick={clickEvent(ids[index])}> ❌ Runs function instantly on render.

<button onClick={() => clickEvent(ids[index])}> ✅ Runs function on an actual click.

